# Sessão do Zend Expira Rápido

Tags: php, zend

Estou tendo problemas com a sessão do Zend pois expira muito rápido, já tentei de tudo!

1- utilizo um controller base, onde todos os outros estendem dele no método init() do controller base já coloquei:

```
Zend_Session::rememberMe(864000);
Zend_Session::start();
```

2- No Apllication.ini

```
;SESSÃO
resources.session.save_path = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/session/"
resources.session.gc_maxlifetime = 864000
resources.session.remember_me_seconds = 864000
```

3- Já mudei as permissões destes arquivos "data/session" para 777

4- já coloquei no bootstrap.php

```
protected function _initSession()
    {
      Zend_Session::rememberMe(864000);
      Zend_Session::start();
      $this->bootstrap('session');        
    }
```

E nada resolveu.

Answer (score 1):

```
$testSpace = new Zend_Session_Namespace('testSpace');
$testSpace->setExpirationSeconds(300, 'accept_answer');
$testSpace->accept_answer = true;
```

Acho que isso ajuda!